# Raid with solid state hybrid drives (sshd) - does it make sense?

Tags: raid

I tried to look along web for an answer but it is hard for me to find a reliable answer.

I know that sshds have an inner, fast ssd cache for blocks that are frequently used. I'm also aware that there is an inner algorithm that manages usage of this cache. And this is fine, I understand how one can gain performance from such a disk.

Now I wanted to create raid 1 from two such sshds (yes, I like my data). But I have doubts if hybrid technology makes sense here. Won't the caching algorithms be fooled by raid? Will it still cache blocks that user frequently use?

Maybe it is smarter to forget about sshds in this scenario and simply create a raid from good old hdds?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A) No the caching wouldn't be confused by RAID.

B) SSHDs never were very good and ceased to be of real use these days, either buy just SSDs if the budget supports it or buy larger disks and put an SSD in front of it and do the caching inside your OS - this works much better as the OS caching software has a view of the actual files you're using and can make better decisions about how to work, an SSHD can only do this based on used blocks so can't be as smart. For Linux use dm-cache or bcache, if you buy Intel SSD/NVMe then their CAS software will do this for Linux or Windows, oh and Windows Storage Spaces will do auto-tiering (not caching but might suit your needs).

Comment: Thank you for insight. I read a little bit more about performance of single hybrid disks and it seems they are really not worth much money. I will go with hdd drives and think about caching - that's something worth reading.

Comment: Also consider https://github.com/stec-inc/EnhanceIO - not sure which linux kernels it's in yet though, looks good but quite new